# Diagonal size increase of container and keep content centered

Tags: css

Hi I want to make a container which includes some boxes with a hr and title. There can be number of boxes in the container and I want the size of the container to increase diagonally up-to the max value, then scrolls. I also want the boxes to be cantered in the container. I have only been able to keep them in a straight line and I can't center the boxes and increase the container size diagonally. How can I do this with CSS?

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} hr {
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
} container {
    max-height: 500px;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(110, 170, 250);
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    overflow: auto;
} boxs {
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 165px);
    height: auto;
    min-width: 160px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
} box {
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <container>
        Title
        <hr>
        <boxs>
            <box></box>
            <box></box>
            <box></box>
            <box></box>
            <box></box>
            <box></box>
        </boxs>
    </container>
</body>
</html>
```

Expecting Output:

[image]

And I really want the boxes to be horizontally centred as in the bottom box should be in centre.

Comment: do you want all the boxes in horizontal?

Comment: What output you are expecting ?

Comment: Question has been edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after. Something like this?

```css
.container {
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  font-size: 17.5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(110, 170, 250);
  padding: 10px 12px;
  margin: 5% 0 0 5%;
}

hr {
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 14px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.boxs {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 165px);
  min-width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Title
  <hr>
  <div class="boxs">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```